# Why selenium can't find some text on page

Tags: python, html, selenium, testing, xpath

I have some page and "tree menu". When I want to open tree_menu, I need to click on button. After, I make some steps and click on title, for example, I clicked "19,20", after I clicked "may" and after I clicked "2" and in the top of page (where i choose this tree_menu) I have a button/link. And text in this element with 2 space (not one):

`"19,20  >  may  >  2"`

But on display I think I see with 1 space, but in tag value with 2. And this ">" is text, but I don't know how it understands and sees selenium.

So, after I call my function for search this text:

```
    def isText(self, text):
        try:
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()[contains(., \"" + text + "\")]]")
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

So, but selenium can't to find this text. And it could find only for "19,20", but space or next text - no.
I opened web-code, but I didn't see new tag or something else.

But I tried find this button/link like element and check that text and it worked.
This project work with dojo, but i can't to change anything.

Please, can you help me with this problem?

TY!
Have a good day!

Comment: What is html tag for the element?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what your intension but if you want to find the button and click using selenium then follow the format.

```
element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH," COPY FULL XPATH").clik()
```

or

```
element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH," COPY FULL XPATH")
time.sleep(5)
element.click()
```

Comment: I use this code actually, but, sorry, it's not about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the tag that contains that text.

```
element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,  "//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(text))
```

Comment: and this didn't resolve my problem. I know this code and it's no work. And it's strange.

Comment: my problem: selenium can't see text in XPath, just part of it. And it works if I find tag bi ID and check text.